# Android Adform banner with Myanmar locale. "The value "၅၀" for key "height" is invalid, and has been ignored

Tags: android, localization, webchromeclient

My application has two languages: English and Myanmar.
When I load AdForm banner with English configuration everything is fine.
However, when I change appplication language to Myanmar banner is not showing, I get the following errors:

[image: console AdWebChromeClient errors]

I assume that at this line:

`banner.setAdSize(new AdSize(320, 50));`

it somehow takes values with wrong Locale. Please help to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to remove line Locale.setDefault(locale), which sets locale for current instance of JVM.

[image: changeLang method with commencted out Locale.setDefault method]